# How to get file name on itemAdded event office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, remote-event-receiver

I am trying get file name after uploading, I am not able to get any properties.
Below is the code i am using.

```
string name="";
if(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties.ContainsKey("LinkFilename"))
                        {
                            name= properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["LinkFilename"].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            name= "No data";
                        }
```

Please help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could get file name from properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterUrl

[image]